# Wordpress get_the_post_thumbnail never returns anything

Tags: wordpress

I having the following widget snippet in a wordpress theme functions file:

```
//display image links
                foreach ($f as $post_id) {
                    echo 'id:'.$post_id;
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
}
```

But get_the_post_thumbnail never returns anything.
Things tried:

- checked $post_id is set correctly
- posts have featured images set
- add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); is set

I don't see what else I can do to solve this

Comment: everything looks fine. where is this being called?

Comment: in a widget class in the functions file

Comment: and `echo 'id:'.$post_id;` gets written in to the widget correctly?

Comment: also, what action are you hooking into to `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Comment: solved it. I've got some strange caching going on in my admin area

Comment: I'm a little late to the game, but would you mind posting more details on what was wrong? I'm having the same problem--pretty sure what I'm doing is correct, but for some reason get_the_post_thumbnail returns nothing.